# Can't access Phpmyadmin in ubuntu error mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lampp

i tried to access phpmyadmin but this thing happen

```
 MySQL said: Documentation

 Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should 
 check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to 
 the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

apache and mysql is running and my website has error like this

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/opt/lampp/temp//sess_ku01nv1mbiroo8btvpbqjv47f7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sisfo/index.php on line 2
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: include in the question`namei -m /opt/lampp/temp/sess_ku01nv1mbiroo8btvpbqjv47f7`. What unix user do your php scripts run as?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Seems like phpmyadmin tries to connect to the mysql socket (which doesn't exist?). You could try to change the host in your `config.inc.php` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

---

```
Warning: session_start(): open(...) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

You probably have wrong permission/ownership for the temporary folder. Try these commands in your shell:

```
chmod 777 /opt/lampp/temp
chown -R 33:33 /opt/lampp/temp
```

Comment: i already change localhost to 127.0.0.1 but still not working